# Firebase push data to JSON array like format

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase for my Android project. I want to push data in a JSON array like format as:

```
mydata 
    0 : "mydata-child0"
    1 : "mydata-child1"
```

Currently what I am getting using the `push()` function is:

```
mydata
    <firebase-unique-id1> : "mydata-child1"
    <firebase-unique-id2> : "mydata-child2"
```

I want to be able to create a new array like structure if the inserted data is the first one. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: There are many very good [reasons why Firebase recommends against using arrays](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html). I highly recommend that you don't change formats and stuck to the IDs generated by calling `push()`.

Comment: Yeah I know but requirement is somewhat like that, is there a nice API to handle this sort of things?

Comment: Instead of push() you can use setValue(). Check out [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data#basic_write)